# SQL create table if variable in another table exists E-R

Tags: sql, database-design, entity-relationship, erd

I have a question regarding how do I create a table if a variable in another table exists. I feel I am quite stuck.

This is a part of my E-R diagram:
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/191/11539017.png/

i have this e-r diagram and I wonder if I have lets say in Val Calc:

```
Val Calc
|-|------|
|A|www...|
|B|www...|
|C|www...|

I want to create three different tables A, B, C with based on the different engagements. like this:

A
|------------|--------------|
|engagement 1|data1|data2|data3|
|engagement 2|data1|data2|data3|
|engagement 3|data1|data2|data3|

B
|------------|--------------|
|engagement 4|dataX|dataY|dataZ|
|engagement 5|dataX|dataY|dataZ|
|engagement 6|dataX|dataY|dataZ|

C
|------------|--------------|
|engagement 7|dataK|dataL|dataM|
|engagement 8|dataK|dataL|dataM|
|engagement 9|dataK|dataL|dataM|
```

How can I accomplish this in a E-R diagram?

Comment: Do the tables always have the same structure? if so there is no reason to create different tables.

Comment: no they don't they have different columns

Comment: Then why do you want different tables? Why not put everything in one table?

Comment: beacuse it would then be null in a lot of columns. To clarify I am storing three diffrent types of .csv files from a SAP dashboards(MS excel). these three imports have different variables which want to be stored as different columns, therefore three different tables. if i would have everything in the same table there would be null where I don't use that variable and i want to be able to select different columns and later and make calculations on these.

Comment: if the columns are the same with the same types how would you get null values? I mean 1 table with the same amount of columns not one table with 12 columns. Also is it always 3? or can it become more?

Answer (score 1):

You can try making another table with a connection to the table that has the same variable. The connection you assign will be a one to one connection between the 2 tables.